# The value mtom is not supported in this context for the binding property message

Tags: wcf, .net-core, binding, mtom

this is an issue I was facing once converting Asp .Net function application which consumed WCF service, to .Net core. WCF service was expecting the HTTP content with encoding type mtom , but it wasn't supported by .Net core, so it issued the exception,
"The value mtom is not supported in this context for the binding property message" once the WCF service is called,

I will be attaching the workaround as well below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install **WcfCoreMtomEncoder** nuget package then
in the reference file when you create bindings for the endpoint,
create basicHttpBinding

```
var transportSecurityBindingElement = new BasicHttpBinding();
```

set desired security and transport mode

```
transportSecurityBindingElement.Security.Mode =BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport; 
transportSecurityBindingElement.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
```

create object with type of custom binding

```
var customTransportSecurityBinding = new CustomBinding(transportSecurityBindingElement);
```

create encoding element using mtomMessage encoder

```
 var encodingElement = new MtomMessageEncoderBindingElement(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement());
```

find and replace the encoding property by iterating the element list of binding

```
for (int i = 0; i < customTransportSecurityBinding.Elements.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (customTransportSecurityBinding.Elements[i] is TextMessageEncodingBindingElement) {
                        customTransportSecurityBinding.Elements[i] = encodingElement;
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

return the custom binding , so it can be used from anywhere

```
  return customTransportSecurityBinding
```

Answer (score 0):

What I know is that WCF does not support some of the MTOM features at the moment, so it will have to wait.

Comment: wcf supports mtom , it's .net core that has issues with it, That's why share it  in the answer section